# Scroll to a specific id within my directive element

Tags: angularjs

I have a full width navigation div on the left hand side of an angular system.

I've successfully set an id on the `<li>` for the active page when doing a full page load.

This is all done within my navigation directive.

The div scrolls when there is a long list of items in it.

What I am trying to do is scroll to the active element within the div but am having no joy.

Within my directive I have successfully found the id using:

```
element.find('#exampleId');
```

but am not sure how to get just this div to scroll to the relevant id.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This would scroll to the bottom of a div with the Id messagesContentElement

```
let messagesContentElement = document.getElementById('messagesContentElement'); 
messagesContentElement.scrollTop = messagesContentElement.scrollHeight;
```

So you need to get the scrollTop value right. Maybe you can calculate this based on a fixed cell height?